# ADT plugin and Eclipse 3.5

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I installed ADT plugin to Eclipse 3.5. But at <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> Android node is not shown.

Comment: Just added a few additions to my answer, in response to your comment.

Comment: This post helped me solve a similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935956/how-to-install-the-android-adt-plugin-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hallelujah. I removed ADT plugin, removed eclipse folder. Also I removed all mentions of eclipse from file system (several folders from user folder). Installed again. And it began work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Subclipse plug-in also installed, then that could be keeping the ADT plug-in from working. They just don't seem to play well together. I created a second Eclipse installation for my Android work with ADT but without Subclipse. I use the other one for projects using Subclipse but not Android. Not ideal but good enough for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

How did you install android?

Did you use the p2 'Install new software' as in:

[image: New update site]

like [this tutorial](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pointgphone.com%2Ftutoriel-installation-sdk-android-51&sl=fr&tl=en&history_state0=)?

See also this [manual page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing), where you will see the update site address is the same, but the process depends on your eclipse version (for eclipse Galileo 3.5.x, the p2 mechanism is recommended)

---

A full reinstall of eclipse is better when in doubt (you do not even need to touch to your previous install: just unzip a new eclipse.zip somewhere): you can even reference your previous workspace (and plugins, if you have uncompressed them in a dedicated directory).
For those references, see **[my eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** for more.
(Note: there is no real full installation of eclipse, except for removing its directory)

Comment: Yes, I installed by using Help->Install New Software. This problem occured after I have updated Eclipse (Help->Check For Updates). After that I tried to reinstall Eclipse and ADT plugin.

Is there a way to full unistall Eclipse? After reinstalling (by removing eclipse folder) it still remember installed plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved this slightly differently.

I am running Eclipse 3.5 under Windows 7 x64. I used the zipped version of Eclipse and originally decompressed it to `c:\program files\eclipse`

I found the only way I could get the ADT plug-in to work was to move the eclipse folder to a folder location with no spaces eg `c:\eclipse` and then run it as an administrator.

After that I just re-installed the ADT plug-in and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and was able to resolve it by simply removing the eclipse and android sub-folders from beneath my C:\user folder.

I was able to leave the main Eclipse folder alone, but I did need to install the Android plugin again.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is so simple, we've overlooked what eclipse is doing when we click "finish" after adding the plugin.

If you take a look at what eclipse is doing in the background before you install the plugin, it's actually installing the program, you'll see the loading bar updating, where ever you have dragged the loading bar to.

So you have to wait for eclipse to install it, it's actually doing something, we just didn't realize it, instead, we quit while eclipse was installing, it never got installed,thus it 'android' doesn't appear in the preferences.

Give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing problem with Updating existing ADT or from Install New Software option of eclipse. Best way to do it

1.Uninstall ADT from eclipse

2.Download ADT Plugin zip file from http://developer.android.com

3.Unzip file downloaded in Step 2 and go to plugins directory.

4.Copy all the jar files from plugins directory to plugins directory of your eclipse.

5.Restart eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Just going to confirm that I has this same problem as well. I would download the ADT but it would not appear in the Window tab for Eclipse (helios) classic. I basically just reinstalled the ADT and that worked fine.

1. In Eclipse I went to the help tab, then Install New Software.
2. I clicked the "whats already installed" link on the right
3. I then uninstalled all the android stuff
4. Then I just reinstalled it again.

Before I restarted Eclipse I waited 2 minutes just in case some files were still installing

Then I closed Eclipse and opened it again and that seemed to do the trick^^

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

I uninstalled the ADT by mistake. The ADT was functioning correctly before this point of time.

Now when I try to install it again, it installs correctly but it doesn't load up in Eclipse. What I mean is that I can see the ADT has been installed when I check the installed plug-ins section; but I cannot see the Android section under Preferences and neither can I see the Android SDK and AVD Manager button/option under Windows.

I am currently using Eclipse 3.5.2 on a Windows 7 x64 system and I do have Subclipse installed as well.

Please advice.

---

Ok. So I got it working by removing Eclipse completely (even the folder under Users). Then while installing everything again, I did not install the Subclipse plug-in and everything is working as it should. I already have a seperate software for managing subversion repositories, so this setup works for me.