# Catch 22, SDK and AVD Manager requires SDK Location, SDK Location requires ADT Update?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

So I just attempted some sort of update using the SDK and AVD Manager in eclipse. I think I just clicked update all, and installed an update. After I installed this, I restarted eclipse, but when it started up again, I got an error message saying that I need to update my ADT to the latest version (14.00) and that mine is version 12.00.

But when I try to go to the SDK and AVD manager to update the ADT it says `Location of the android SDK has not been set in the preferences`

So then when I go to preferences and look at the SDK location it says `This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0 or above.  Current version is 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.  Please update ADT to the latest version.`

Do I need to somehow manually update the SDK? I am not really sure what happened here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT plugin and Eclipse 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696432/adt-plugin-and-eclipse-3-5)

Comment: So you are suggesting that I might need to completely uninstall eclipse and ADT, and reinstall? That sounds so messy.

Comment: I didn't suggest anything. :) I just pointed to another question that seemed to address the same issue.

Comment: Well, it seems you pointed in the right direction, thanks haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had this issue and what I did was completely remove the ADT, SDK's, tools, everything and then re-install and update. I did not have to delete Eclipse though.

EDIT:

[Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) is a link to the AVD revision information site. If you look at the different versions, it will tell you the required SDK tools version. When this happened to me, I remember it saying something like "if you have less than version 14 then you must update manually" ... but I was unable to find it.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) is a link to the SDK tools revision information site.

Comment: Weird, so there is some problem with the updater. It would be cool if there was a button that you could use to submit a question to google so that they could figure out what is causing this.